# How to wire in-duct heat strip to geothermal unit with nest thermostat

Tags: wiring, hvac, thermostat, heating, electric-heat

I have installed a new in-duct heat strip for my geothermal heat pump.

**Heat strip:** Warren SL20A Electric Duct Heater

**Heat pump furnace:** GeoCool 5 Ton

**Thermostat:** Google Nest 3rd Gen

My situation is I have a leak coming from the evaporator coil and needs to be replaced. While I wait for warranty to replace me a new one I need to keep the house warm. I'm trying to figure out how to wire the heat strip to the furnace, controlling it with the thermostat. I can't afford short circuit any components right now so I'm hesitant to try it on my own.

Here's what I'm trying to figure out:

1. How to set it up to run ONLY with heat strip. (Compressor and pump must NOT turn on)
2. How to set it up to run simultaneously with heat pump (so the compressor doesn't run too long)
3. Understanding if 2nd stage option is necessary for the heat strip. (Should I use it or should I not) What are some of the situations I need 2nd phase?
4. On my thermostat whenever I try to have the fan run separately it runs at the lowest speed possible. How do you control fan speed through the thermostat?

The attached image shows wiring diagram for the heat strip, heat pump, and thermostat.
[image: wiring diagram]

**UPDATE 1:** I have more questions arrowed in the picture below:

- a). Should I splice the common wire 3 ways?
- b). On the heat strip it says "Step 1". I'm guessing that goes to "AUX" on the thermostat but if you look at the heat pump there's an "AUX" option with "W" and "B" slot. I don't understand how to wire that.
- c). On the heat pump there's an "E" option. I'm guessing it's for emergency heat. Am I splicing 3 ways with the "*" slot on the thermostat and the "Step 2" on the heat strip?

****Also the "RH" option on the thermostat. Will I be using that since there's a separate unit heating instead of the heat pump?****
[image: wiring diagram Edit 1]

Comment: way above my pay grade, I thought you just do not want the compressor to run (due to the leak) while you want the duct heater to work

Comment:  I wish that was my only problem. The heat pump board makes it so complicated.